# How to store date from R to MongoDB with RMongo package?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongo

I want to send data from R to MongoDB with RMongo package

I was able to do it with mongolite package. And also want to do it with RMongo package

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you want to use RMongo if mongoilite is working already? BTW, RMongo has not been updated for quite some time.

Comment: Just to Learn. I want to know if I can do the same with RMongo.